# Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at ): with devise mailer

Tags: email, devise, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-2.7

i have got weird issue while working with my application.
In My app there will be lot mailer options which is write by own and it works perfectly. I have used Devise gem Authentication and those mails like (registration, forgot password, confirmation) mails are not working. End up with issue

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  # config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :user_name => ENV['sendgrid_username'],
    :password => ENV['sendgrid_password'],
    :domain => '*****.com',
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

I dont know why i am getting the devise mailer issue, other custom mailers are working fine.

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10789ms (ActiveRecord: 4434.0ms | Allocations: 260142)
>
> Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at):

I have inherited the mail in my custom mailer even though i have got same issue.

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

  default from: "default@mydomain.com"

  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    @token = token
    devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions, opts)
  end

  def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    @token = token
    devise_mail(record, :reset_password_instructions, opts)
  end

  def unlock_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    @token = token
    devise_mail(record, :unlock_instructions, opts)
  end

  def email_changed(record, opts={})
    devise_mail(record, :email_changed, opts)
  end

  def password_change(record, opts={})
    devise_mail(record, :password_change, opts)
  end

  # you can then put any of your own methods here
end
```